# rangeRoundBands outerPadding in bar chart way too big

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am new to D3.js and have a problem with my vertical bar chart. For some reason, the distance between the axis and the bars is way too big when I use rangeRoundBands for scaling. 
In the API, it is explained like this:

[image]

So the problem seems to be the outerPadding. But setting the outerPadding to zero does not help. However, when I use rangeBands instead, the problem disappears and the bars are positioned correctly, right below the axis. But then I will get these nasty antialiasing effects, so this is not really an option. Here is my code:

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = x - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .15, 0);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("top");

    var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

    var xAxis3 = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("");

    var svg = d3.select("#plotContainer").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.size;
    })).nice();
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    }));

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .call(xAxis);
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis2);
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis3);

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                return d.size < 0 ? "bar negative" : "bar positive";
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return x(Math.min(0, d.size));
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return y(d.name);
            })
            .attr("width", function(d) {
                return Math.abs(x(d.size) - x(0));
            })
            .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
            .append("title")
            .text(function(d) {
                return "This value is " + d.name;
            });
    ;

    svg.selectAll(".bar.positive")
            .style("fill", "steelblue")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).style("fill", "yellow");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).style("fill", "steelblue");
            });

    svg.selectAll(".bar.negative")
            .style("fill", "brown")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).style("fill", "yellow");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).style("fill", "brown");
            });

    svg.selectAll(".axis")
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
            .style("stroke", "#000")
            .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

    svg.selectAll(".grid")
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
            .style("opacity", "0.7");

    svg.selectAll(".grid.path")
            .style("stroke-width", "0");
```

EDIT:
Please take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GUYZk/9/

My problem is reproducible there. You cannot alter the outerPadding with rangeRoundBands, whereas rangeBands behaves normal.

Comment: It helps to have the data and any css styling as well. This way one can place it in jsfiddle and analyze it fully. Alternatively, and better, you can create a fiddle yourself. It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I have put your code in a JS fiddle and added some data (minor adjustment needed). Is this what you are seeing? http://jsfiddle.net/GUYZk/

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Apparently, my error is related to the data. The Y domain is in my case an identifier like "ABCD1000", "ABCD1020" and so on. Unfortunately, I cannot provide the whole dataset. When I replace it with dummy data, which I also did in your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/GUYZk/2/), It looks fine. But with real data it looks like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zo6l4im5tjdhogi/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2013.56.10.png

Comment: Comparison to using RangeBands instead: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nadjdpd299cb8ay/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2014.00.44.png

Comment: Are you using the latest version of D3? Might explain the discrepancy between how it is working for you and the JSfiddle example. Also, are you doing some pre processing (I notice they are ordered in your images) if so adding that code my make the example represent your issue.

Comment: Yes I am using v3.4.6. The sorting function has nothing to do with it, it looks the same when I remove it. However, I took the time to alter the data used in the fiddle so that it looks just like my real data, and I can somehow reproduce the effect now:
http://jsfiddle.net/GUYZk/7/
If you replace RangeRoundBands with RangeBands, you can see that the bars are much closer to axis. The effect is not as big as with my real data though...

Comment: Ok after dumping a whole dataset into the fiddle, it is 100% reproducable: http://jsfiddle.net/GUYZk/8/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR:** this is a consequence of the math. To work around, use `rangeBands` to lay out the bars, and use [`shape-rendering: crispEdges`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) in CSS to align them to pixel boundaries.

---

**Full explanation:**

Because the `rangeRoundBands` function must distribute the bars evenly throughout the provided pixel range *AND* it must also provide an integer `rangeBand`, it uses `Math.floor` to chop off the fractional bit of each successive bar.

The reason this extra outer padding compounds with longer datasets is because all those fractional pixels have to end up *somewhere*. The author of this function chose to evenly split them between the beginning and the end of the range.

Because the fraction pixel of each rounded bar is on the interval `(0, 1)`, the extra pixels glommed onto each end will span about 1/4 of the data bar count. With 10 bars, 2-3 extra pixels would never be noticed, but if you have 100 or more, the extra 25+ pixels become much more noticeable.

One possible solution that appears to work in Chrome for `svg:rect`: use `rangeBands` to lay out, but then apply [`shape-rendering: crispEdges`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) as a CSS style to your bar paths/rects.

This then leaves the onus on the SVG renderer to nudge each bar to a pixel boundary, but they are more evenly spaced overall, with occasional variance in the spacing to account for the error over the whole chart.

Personally, I use `shape-rendering: optimizeSpeed` and let the rendering agent make whatever tradeoffs it must to quickly render the (potentially fractional) bar positions.

Comment: FWIW: I just added some clarification around this to the D3 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I came to this answer with the same problem; Ben's answer suggests another simple (but likely slower) workaround; you could fix a padding by shifting all x values to the left by the first value in the computed range.

Example:

```
// set your desired gap between y-axis and first bar
var yGap = 5;

// create your scale
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataArray)
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

// obtain the *computed* left edge of the first bar
var leftOuter = xScale.range()[0];

// when setting the x attribute of your rects:
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d) - leftOuter + yGap; });
```

The last line shifts everything to the left by an amount such that the left outer padding is your chosen `yGap` and the right outer padding is whatever it needs to be to make up the difference.  Essentially this overrides the creator's intention of splitting the excess padding between the left and right sides.

I hope someone else finds this useful!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and no matter I used for inner padding or outer padding, I just could not get the ticks align at the center of my vertical bars on the X-Axis. So I have not used the inner or outer padding. I have used my own padding, say 0.1.

for the bar rect, I set the width as

```
width: (1.0 - padding) * xScale.rangeBand()
```

for the x I just add half of the padding like this.

```
x: padding * xScale.rangeBand() / 2
```

This made the ticks perfectly align with the vertical bands.